# html toggle switch button goes to another page when clicked

Tags: php, html, css

I have got a switch from https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/
What I want to do is when is it clicked to yes it goes to another page, when on the 2nd page it stays on, if you click again it goes back to the 1st page?
Is this possible?

Comment: It sure is possible.

Comment: It is absolutely possible - even probable. How do you plan to store the value on the server side? HTTP is stateless, so it won't store values such as "Has the user clicked the button." Have you considered cookies or even a session?

Comment: how about using this onClick="parent.location='index.html'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The switch is simply a masked checkbox, so you can proceed like this:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('switch_id').addEventListener("change", function(){
        if (this.checked) window.location.href = 'http://www.mynewpage.com';
    });
</script>
```

You can also "fake" the checkbox on the second page, in the sense that you can make always checked and always not checked in the first page.